# InheritableThreadLocal variable value not inherited by child thread

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to execute the below code:

```
public class Basecl
{

    public static InheritableThreadLocal<Integer> myValue = new InheritableThreadLocal<Integer>();
    
    public void setMyValue(Integer i)
    {
        myValue.set(i);
    }

    public Integer getMyValue()
    {
        return myValue.get();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void bClass(ITestContext context, XmlTest xt)
    {
        System.out.println("Before Class called - " + context.getName() + " - " + this.getClass().getName() + " - " +  "Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        setMyValue(12);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void bmeth1(ITestContext context, XmlTest xt, Method m, Object a[], ITestResult itr)
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method called - " + context.getName() + " - " + this.getClass().getName() + " - " + m.getName() + " - " + "Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void ameth1(ITestContext context, XmlTest xt, Method m, Object a[], ITestResult itr)
    {
        System.out.println("After Method called - " + context.getName() + " - " + this.getClass().getName() + " - " + m.getName() + " - " + "Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

}
```

The above class is inherited by the test class:

```
public class TC_009 extends Basecl
{

    @Test
    public void tCase3(ITestContext context, XmlTest xt)
    {
        System.out.println("My Value in testcase 3 is : " + getMyValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void tCase4(ITestContext context, XmlTest xt)
    {
        System.out.println("My Value in testcase 4 is : " + getMyValue());
    }

}
```

**Below is the testng.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name = "Suite" parallel = "methods" thread-count = "5" allow-return-values = "true" verbose = "0" configfailurepolicy = "continue">
<test name="Test1">
    <classes>
        <class name="testing.TC_009"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

I am executing the above test methods in parallel by running the testng.xml file. As per my understanding the value of the inheritable thread-local variable can be accessed by the child threads.
But when I execute the above test class, I observed that in the test method `tcase4`, the value of inheritable threadlocal variable `myValue` is `null`.
As per my understanding the "BeforeMethods" and the "test methods" are the child threads of the BeforeClass method.

**Below is the output:**

```
Before Class called - Test1 - testing.TC_009 - Thread id: 12
Before Method called - Test1 - testing.TC_009 - tCase3 - Thread id: 11
Before Method called - Test1 - testing.TC_009 - tCase4 - Thread id: 12
tCase4 called
tCase3 called
My Value in testcase 4 is : 12
My Value in testcase 3 is : null
After Method called - Test1 - testing.TC_009 - tCase4 - Thread id: 12
After Method called - Test1 - testing.TC_009 - tCase3 - Thread id: 11
```

So, why the value of inheritable threadlocal variable `myValue` is `null` in the test method `tcase4` ?

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding the "BeforeMethods" and the "test methods" are the child threads of the BeforeClass method.

Not at all.

You didn't explain how you run these tests in parallel.

In any case, `InheritableThreadLocal` does not mean what you think it means. An InheritableThreadLocal is **identical** to a normal ThreadLocal: Each thread has its own version of that variable.

The one teensy tiny difference is simply this: Normal `ThreadLocal` instances default to 'the default value' (you can configure this in the constructor of ThreadLocal, and if you fail to do that, it's `null`). InheritableThreadLocals default to the value of the thread that made the new thread.

So, at the moment you call `thread.start()`, that thread's value for its thread local is cloned **at that moment in time** from the thread you ran `thread.start()` from. From there on out its its own thing.

SOURCE: Read javadoc.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have edited my question to include the testng.xml file which I use to run the test methods in parallel.

Comment: When I see the thread ids in the output, the first BeforeMethod and it's corresponding test method has the same thread id as the BeforeClass method. Can you please clear this doubt ?

Comment: What 'doubt' - yes, one thread first runs your `@BeforeClass` method, and will then run one of the test cases, whilst another thread is booted up that runs the other test case. This is, test-runner-spec-wise, perfectly fine. If you need more specific behaviour than that, you should make your own Thread objects in your own test cases instead.